# servlet-api missing from Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets

First of all, I want to apologize for maybe duplicate topic but I couldn't find an answer that solves my problem. After i create a new Maven Project, i have the following error:

```
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

I added the jar servlet-api manually, but the problem is still there. How may i solve this? I am using Spring framework 3.2.0.RELEASE, JAVA 7

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a dependecy to your POM!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For servlet API 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

clean the project and Right Click on project -> Maven -> Update Project.